# how to change background progressView circle from color to an image?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiprogressview

I want to make a `progressView` circle. I followed one sample code that was working with background color but now I want to use background image instead of the background color.

This is the current sample code : [Sample Code](http://www.mediafire.com/download/l4lhfkhu3gq7vaa/KKProgressTimer-master.zip)

Please see this sample code and guide me on how to change background color to background image (There are two images in the project namely : `background.png` & `front.png`).

Thanks.

this is my code :

**KKProgressTimer.m**

```
- (void)setupParams {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.frameWidth = 3;
    self.progressColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
    self.progressBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"front"]];
    self.circleBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

when run project my background don't fit in my view!!!

Answer (score 0):

The property is defined there for changing the background color `@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *progressBackgroundColor;` and is you want to use the image then UIColor class have method `+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image;` you can use with your image.

```
self.circleBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
```

Comment: my friend I use this method but why my image is so big in my uiview...how to fit this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change `UIActivityView` but you can replace it with a rotating `UIImageView`. Create a category and follow like this:

```
- (void) setRotation:(float)duration
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2*M_PI)];
    rotation.duration = duration; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
    [self.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
}
```

You can make an `UIImageView` and rotate it like this:

```
[self.imgProgress setRotation:1];
```